# Can we know how many IO times happened when using Stream

Tags: java

Is there any way to know how many IO times happened when we use streams?

Comment: What do you mean? Pure I/O wait CPU time? You do know that writing to sockets never generates any?

Comment: What do you want to measure? If you use buffered streams they do some buffering. Probablu OS is doing some buffering too (if you mean something like hard drive read/writes etc.). I think it's very hard to measure.

Answer (score 0):

You can count how many times you perform a read or write to a Stream.  With buffering and coalescing (there are many kinds) the number of calls will be different (in fact its the purpose of these to reduce the number of calls to improve throughput, sometimes at the cost of latency)

Comment: how to get such count number? say, I want to compare BufferedInputStream and FileInputStream

Comment: Create an InputStream which wraps another input stream which counts how many times it is called.  IMHO, you are far better off measuring how long it takes rather than the number of calls.  Otherwise you will get two numbers but have little idea what they mean.